# What is an arbitrary element in Python?

Tags: python, set, element

I'm reading about sets and see terms like "specific" elements and "arbitrary" elements. For example:
"The method remove removes a specific element from a set; pop removes an arbitrary element".
Can someone explain arbitrary elements?

Comment: *Arbitrary* means *not specific*. *Specific* means a specifyed one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ar·bi·trar·y `ˈärbəˌtrerē/`
>   adjective,
>   based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system.

In the context of your question, "arbitrary element" simply means an element not chosen by you. From the program's perspective, the element was chosen randomly and unpredictably.

Consider:

```
x = set([1,2]).pop()
```

`x` might have the value `1` or `2`, but you cannot predict beforehand which one it will be.

Comment: From the looks of it its popping from the top. Similar to a stack

Comment: A `set` doesn't have a top or bottom, nor front or back. That's what makes the choice arbitrary.

Comment: I have tried the following and get the same results each time...the elements that are "popped" start from the beginning of the set. 

nums = {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 6}

number=nums.pop()
print(number)
number=nums.pop()
print(number)
number=nums.pop()
print(number)
number=nums.pop()
print(number)

Comment: @jasmine - what do you mean by "*beginning of the set*"? A set has no beginning.

Comment: @Robᵩ it is printing 1, 2, 3, 4 every single time...it does not seem to be random

Comment: Try again with `nums = {"Washington", "Adams", "Jefferson", "Madison"}` If you have access to both Python2 and Python3, run it in each interpreter. I believe that you'll see that neither "order of insertion" nor "smallest first" will predict the order of retrieval.

Comment: @Robᵩ I have realized a moment ago with another set example of strings, it gives random just as it does with the example you have provided. Is there a reason it is not random with numbers?

Comment: It isn't random, it is arbitrary. The choice is made by a deterministic process, just one that isn't documented or guaranteed to be preserved from release to release.

Answer (score 5):

Sets are unordered.

The remove command takes the element that you specify.

The pop takes any element. There's no way of predicting which

Answer (score 0):

It is the element which is decided by a without any rule or arbiter rather than by a specific rule and structure. In Mathematics X+X = 2X where X is the arbitrary value which not defined in the  equation.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I've seen, the pop method removes an arbitrary element from the set. In the case of numbers, it removes the lesser positive number
e.g
 nums = {4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1 ,-3}
 print(nums)
 nums.add(-7)
 nums.pop()
 print(nums)

RESULT:
  {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, -3}
  {3, 4, 5, 6, -7, -3}